# Data visualisation (plot,patch,trisruf) too slow in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, plot, visualization

I am stuck with a problem;

I have a cell array [mxn] with holds xy-polygons. Generally m = [1000;9000] and n = [10-20], where m is related to the z-height of each polygon. The polgyons are translated into f,v patches in a for loop. A second cell array holds values between 1 and 0. The second cell array is used to color each patch (where four tresholds are set to color green, yellow, orange and red). When I plot the data, manipulation (rotation etc.) becomes impossible as it seems this operation is too computationally expensive.

Any advice on how to lower the computation overhead would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code so we can see better how to improve it

Comment: Make sure to use `set(gcf, 'Renderer','OpenGL')` on your figure (gcf) before drawing to set rendering mode to opengl.

Comment: Well, life's hard :P. You will need to lower the amount of data plotted probably. One of the ways is to compute the "surface" and only plot that, but its not a straightforward problem.